# Android TV control focus from imageViewA in fragmentA to another imageViewB in fragmentB

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, television

I am building an app for Google TV ，I Have a FragmentActivity ActivityA , and three Fragment FragmentA 、FragmentB 、FragmentC，in each fragment there are some ImageView.

Just as the pic shows below:

http://drp.io/files/541275c964ae0.png

MainActivityGameLTV2 ：

```
public class MainActivityGameLTV2 extends FragmentActivity{

private static final String TAG ="MainActivityGameLTV2";
private WoDouViewPager mViewPager;

//记录当前选中位置
private int currentIndex;

//主页页面数量
private static final int PAGE_NUMBER = 3;

private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_game_lt_v2);

    initView();

    initData();

}

private void initData() {
    initFragment();
}

private void initView() {
    mViewPager = (WoDouViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_game_v2); 
}

/**
 * 初始化Fragment
 */
private void initFragment() {
    fragments.clear();//清空
    int count = PAGE_NUMBER;

    MainGameLeftFragment fragmentLeft = new MainGameLeftFragment();
    MainGameMiddleFragment fragmentMiddle = new MainGameMiddleFragment();
    MainGameRightFragment fragmentRight = new MainGameRightFragment();
    fragments.add(fragmentLeft);
    fragments.add(fragmentMiddle);
    fragments.add(fragmentRight);

    MainActivityGameLTV2FragmentAdapter mAdapter = new MainActivityGameLTV2FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageListener);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);// 共三页设置第二页居中
}

/**
 * ViewPager切换监听方法
 */
public ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener pageListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }
  };
}
```

view_pager_game_v2.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ViewPager
        android:background="@drawable/wodou_bj"
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_game_v2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivityGameLTV2FragmentAdapter ：

```
public class MainActivityGameLTV2FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Fragment> mFragments;
    private FragmentManager fm;

    public MainActivityGameLTV2FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm,ArrayList<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        mFragments = fragments;
        this.fm=fm;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return mFragments.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }
}
```

MainGameRightFragment :FragmentA:

```
public class MainGameRightFragment extends WoDouGameBaseFragment{

ImageView mIv_01;
ImageView mIv_02;
ImageView mIv_03;
ImageView mIv_04;
ImageView mIv_05;
ImageView mIv_06;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.main_game_right_fragment, null);

    initView(view);
    return view;
}

private void initView(View view) {
    mIv_01 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.wodou_01);
    mIv_02 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.wodou_02);
    mIv_03 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.wodou_03);
    mIv_04 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.wodou_04);
    mIv_05 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.wodou_05);
    mIv_06 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.wodou_06);

    mIv_01.setOnFocusChangeListener(mFocusChangeListener);
    mIv_02.setOnFocusChangeListener(mFocusChangeListener);
    mIv_03.setOnFocusChangeListener(mFocusChangeListener);
    mIv_04.setOnFocusChangeListener(mFocusChangeListener);
    mIv_05.setOnFocusChangeListener(mFocusChangeListener);
    mIv_06.setOnFocusChangeListener(mFocusChangeListener);

    }
 }
```

main_game_right_fragment.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/titleview_myapps_about"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.04"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/wodou_01"
            android:layout_width="206dp"
            android:nextFocusRight="@+id/wodou_02"
            android:layout_height="205dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sharp_background"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/wodou_game_01"
            android:tag="#FF666666"
            android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
            android:alpha="255"/>
    <ImageButton`enter code here`
            android:id="@+id/wodou_04"
            android:layout_width="206dp"
            android:layout_height="205dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sharp_background"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/wodou_game_04"
            android:tag="#FF666666"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/wodou_05"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/wodou_01"/>


    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/wodou_02"
            android:layout_width="446dp"
            android:layout_height="420dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:nextFocusRight="@+id/wodou_03"
            android:background="@drawable/sharp_background"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/wodou_game_02"
            android:tag="#FF666666"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/wodou_01"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/wodou_04"/>

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/wodou_03"
            android:layout_width="423dp"
            android:layout_height="205dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sharp_background"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/wodou_game_03"
            android:tag="#FF666666"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/wodou_02"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/wodou_02"/>
    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/wodou_05"
            android:layout_width="206dp"
            android:layout_height="205dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sharp_background"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/wodou_game_05"
            android:tag="#FF666666"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/wodou_02"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/wodou_03"/>

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/wodou_06"
            android:layout_width="206dp"
            android:layout_height="205dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sharp_background"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/wodou_game_06"
            android:tag="#FF666666"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/wodou_05"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/wodou_03"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now i use D-pad move my focus from ImageView IV_2 in FragmentA to IV_7 in FragmentB,however it do not work as I want .More often when I use D-pad move focus from IV_2 , the focus goes to IV_8 or other imageView in FragmentB！

For this I use android:nextFocusRight to specify the next focus right view ,but it do not work.

How can i control focus when i focused at IV_2 in FragmentA move to IV_7 in FragmentB ?

Answer (score 3):

this below sample code will help you to move focus from one view element to another:

```
    public class DpadActivity extends Activity { 

    private ImageView iv1,iv2; 
    private static Toast tst; 
    private int current_position=1; 

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dpad); 
        iv1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 
        iv2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView2); 

        iv1.requestFocus(); 
        iv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hilight); 


        iv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "iv2 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } 
        }); 


        iv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "iv1 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } 
        }); 



        tst.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ha hai", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 

        if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER == keyCode 
                || KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER == keyCode) { 
                tst.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            return true; 
        } else if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT == keyCode) { 
        tst.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Left Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            return true; 
        } else if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT == keyCode) { 
            tst.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Right Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            return true; 
        } else if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP == keyCode) { 
            if(current_position==1) 
            { 
                iv2.requestFocus(); 
                current_position=2; 
            }else if(current_position==2) 
            { 
                iv1.requestFocus(); 
                current_position=1; 
            } 
            tst.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Up Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            return true; 
        } else if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN == keyCode) { 
            if(current_position==1) 
            { 
                iv2.requestFocus(); 
                current_position=2; 
            }else if(current_position==2) 
            { 
                iv1.requestFocus(); 
                current_position=1; 
            } 
            tst.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Down Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            return true; 

        } 

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing Detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
        } 
    }
```